# Specific question on Sn modules

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $L_{-1}$ denote the 1-dimensional sign-representation of the symmetric
group $S_n$ and V the standard $(n - 1)$-dimensional module for $S_n$. How to prove that V and $V \otimes L_{-1}$
are not isomorphic if n > 3.

Comment: Silly question: For each $n$, how many isomorphism classes of simple $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$-modules $V$ are such that $V \otimes L_{-1} \cong V$? Starting at $n=2$, we get 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, .... Is it non-decreasing? Asymptotic behavior?

Comment: @Serkan yes, but it doesn't seem obvious to me how to count them. Like squares are symmetric, but they only exist for square n. L's are symmetric but they only exist for odd n.

Answer (score 2):

When $n > 3$, the element $(12)$ has trace $n - 3 \neq 0$ on $V$. Thus, $V$ and $L_{-1} \otimes V$ has different characters.